# Streambuilder not working after updating data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to fix my streambuilder to show that i changed data after I update a field in the database but it doesnt seem to work

Any help would be appreciated

```
          StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("employees")
                        .doc(employee.uid)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Info(
                            myController: controller,
                            label: "First Name",
                            value: employee.firstname,
                            onPressed: () {
                              FirestoreDatabase database = FirestoreDatabase();
                              database.update(
                                  uid: employee.uid,
                                  attribute: 'firstname',
                                  value: controller.text);
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),
```

Function for updating

```
Future<void> update({uid, attribute, value}) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('employees')
        .doc(uid)
        .update({attribute: value});
  }
```

Database
[image: database]

Comment: Did you mention which collection you are trying to update?
i did not see it .

Comment: im trying to update the employees document, more specifically the employee fields

Comment: here is a screenshot of my database https://imgur.com/zg3DYmn

Comment: @masumbillahsanjid and i update the info in database.update()

Comment: Look how i updated my collection https://notepad.pw/code/gaus1p2z9

Comment: Did you see your collection from firebase console after updating , is this really made effect on your database?

Comment: Thing is im updating an attribute whenever i click on submit, depending on which attribute the user clicks on, and i use a widget to store the data of each employee

Comment: let me show you what i mean through screenshots https://imgur.com/a/vT8rZlF

Comment: @masumbillahsanjid yes the updating works, i just want it to show up in my screen whenever i update

Comment: value: employee.firstname where did it come from?
you need to pass your data snaphsot.data like this

Comment: it comes from the database, can u specify more

Comment: how can i use the snapshot data with employee.firstname

Comment: Check this article how they show https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-firestore-database/